# scanf doesn't read in int properly

Tags: c, scanf

I've also tried adding fflush(stdout); after the printf statement and that didn't do anything, and neither did using fflush(stdin) before the scanf

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float cost(int qty)
{
    if (qty <= 20)
        return qty * 23.45;
    if (qty >= 21 && qty <= 100)
        return qty * 21.11;
    if (qty > 100)
        return qty * 18.75;
    return '0';
}

// void main() VS Only
int main()
{
    int q;

    printf("Enter quantity of books wanted: ");
    scanf("&d", &q);

    printf("\n\nThe total cost for purchasing books is: $%0.2f\n\n", cost(q));
}
```

Comment: What exact incorrect behaviour are you observing? Give the exact input, expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: `#include <conio.h>`  add this

Comment: Note: `return '0';` probably does not do what you think it does. ITYM `return 0;`.

Comment: Renatus, the biggest mistake is not fully enabling warnings.  Save time.  Enable them all.  `scanf("&d", &q);` should get a warning such as "warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]"/

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of scanf() function is wrong.
The format caractere is "%d" for int. 
You put "&d".

You can call a system("PAUSE") to keep the terminal open and see the result.

```
...
scanf("%d", &q);
...
system("PAUSE");
```

scanf() sample and reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 1):

You have passed wrong format specifier for integer, change this `scanf("&d", &q);` to `scanf("%d", &q);`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `scanf("%d",&q)`
There should be `%` before datatype.
Datatype - `d` for `int`
`&d` to `%d`